# Optimize sympy expression evaluation by combining as many free symbols as possible

Tags: python, sympy

Imagine I have an unknown, quite complex expression that I need to repeatedly evaluate numerically, e.g.:

```
my_expr = (a*b*c**2 - 2*sqrt(d*(a*b-c-e+x)))/(b - 1)
```

Each time I reevaluate the expression, the only symbol that changes is 'x', so it makes sense for me to precompute all the others (I will be using c code generation eventually).

So what I want is to automatically pull out and combine as many free symbols as possible in advance, except for x. This would work a bit like cse, but making the final expression contain as few calculations as possible.

e.g. for the above I might end up with a system equivalent to this:

```
var1 = a*b*c**2
var2 = a*b-c-e
var3 = b - 1
my_new_expr = (var1-2*sqrt(d*(var2+x)))/var3
```

This means I can precalculate var1,var2 & var3, and the repeated calculation (my_new_expr) is as simple as possible computationally.

Is there anyway I can do this in sympy? I've looked through all the simplification methods etc, including collect etc, and none quite do what I need. Failing that, is there any traversal of the expression I could do to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just substitute values for `a, b, c, ...` first to get an expression in terms of `x` only?

Comment: Hi, because by the time i evaluate the expression (in C++) I don't have access to sympy. Plus I won't know the values of a, b, c etc until I've already left sympy, so there's no opportunity for substitution.

Comment: You can traverse the expression using `.args`: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although my `model` branch at sympy/smichr has a more comprehensive solution, the following will do pretty well at condensing those sub-expressions that are constant:

```
def condense(eq, *x):
    """collapse additive/multiplicative constants into single
    variables, returning condensed expression and replacement
    values.

    Examples
    ========

    Simple constants are left unchanged

    >>> condense(2*x + 2, x)
    (2*x + 2, {})

    More complex constants are replaced by a single variable

    >>> first = condense(eq, x); first
    (c6*(c5 - 2*sqrt(d*(c4 + x))), {c4: a*b - c - e, c6: 1/(b - 1), c5: a*b*c**2})

    If a condensed expression is expanded, there may be more simplification possible:

    >>> second = condense(first[0].expand(), x); second
    (c0 + c2*sqrt(c1 + d*x), {c1: c4*d, c2: -2*c6, c0: c5*c6})
    >>> full_reps = {k: v.xreplace(first[1]) for k, v in second[1].items()}; full_reps
    {c1: d*(a*b - c - e), c2: -2/(b - 1), c0: a*b*c**2/(b - 1)}

    More than 1 variable can be designated:

    >>> condense(eq, c, e)
    (c4*(c**2*c1 - 2*sqrt(d*(-c + c2 - e))), {c4: 1/(b - 1), c1: a*b, c2: a*b + x})
    """
    reps = {}
    con = numbered_symbols('c')
    free = eq.free_symbols
    def c():
        while True:
            rv = next(con)
            if rv not in free:
                return rv
    def do(e):
        i, d = e.as_independent(*x)
        if not i.args: return e
        return e.func(reps.get(i, reps.setdefault(i, c())), d)
    rv = eq.replace(lambda x: x.is_Add or x.is_Mul, lambda x: do(x))
    reps = {v: k for k, v in reps.items()}
    keep = rv.free_symbols & set(reps)
    reps = {k: reps[k].xreplace(reps) for k in keep}
    return rv, reps
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks so much! Has been a good way to learn some deeper sympy too.